# WCF architecture help needed

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture, wcf-binding, wcf-security

We are planning on implementing our new software application as shown below.

Does this architecture look fit for purpose?

**Items to Note:**

- There are many PC's
- The pc has a WCF client as it needs to upload data to the
  database periodically.
- The PC has a server because the end user on the terminal server needs
  to be able to interrogate the pc for information
- The terminal server is the GUI for users so they can remotely connect
  to a specific PC to interrogate the pc for information
- We are using basicHttpBinding below

**What else have we considered?**

- We have tried WCF NetPeerTcpBinding (i.e P2P) but it does not support
  request-reply operations.
- We have tried WCF Duplex but with the requirements listed above in the items to note section we would end up with a client and server at both ends anyway.

[image]

Comment: I disagree with your second point in "What we have considered." Last week I tested WCF duplex using TCP instead of HTTP and it worked perfectly without having to open up a `server->client` channel. I actually tested and got that working via internet, thru firewalls and NATs.

Comment: Just to confirm in a few words: You want to send data from a client->server application to upload data. You also want the server to periodically ask the client for it to upload data too?

Comment: @HighCore yes you can and i have done that aswell. but i need the pc to also talk to the application server and initiate this commnication itself - so i ended up putting a client and server at both ends anyway.

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz yes you are correct. The OperationContracts at each end are different.

Comment: @user1438082: Creating a client w/ duplex and running it under a service context should be fine. at startup it can establish a connection allowing for pass/receive. You can also place failsafes (on connection dropped/no internet/etc.) then have a client UI tie in to the local service. This also saves you from creating a look-up table of sorts too, as once subscribed the server is already aware of prospect to communicate with.

Comment: @BradChristie Would you be able to add this solution as an image to an answer so i can see clearly what you are referring to?

Comment: Does the client need a UI as well?

Comment: @BradChristie A UI exists only on the terminal server.

Comment: I would use duplex communication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184.aspx instead of Client/Server on both sides... did you tried to use registered callbacks / publish-subscribe-pattern instead of a server running at the System Agent? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx

Comment: hi beachwalker - no i did try callbacks but i need to go look at your links to see if i am missing something.

Comment: so how does publish/subscribe operate when a user on the terminal server wants to view a list of folders on an agent (i.e execute a method on the agent)? Also i have many agents and i will typically only want to talk with one of them from the terminal server. Every hour each agent needs to insert a log in the database.

Comment: Is this whole setup running on a separate network, with the terminal server the only point of entry? And what kind of information is the application server interrogating the agent PC for?

Comment: it will all run on an intranet - yes the terminal server is the only point of entry for a user. The agent will every hour update the database though. The application interrogates the pc to browse the hard drive via the agent and also to give the agent jobs to do

Comment: Have you considered using protobuf instead of WCF? Just wondering since you say `many pc's` and full duplex...

Comment: no i have not - we want to stick with Microsoft technologies

Comment: So it seems you have two tasks? One, creating a windows service that periodically sending data to your server; and two, reinventing a VPN?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic it is not reinventing a vpn. its an intranet application that lets the user on the terminal server browse items. the items could be files/folders/hardware/registry etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I apologize but I basically disagree with your architecture.

- WCF is not designed or suited for anything other than a request-response communication.
  Its full duplex ability will not enable your server side to issue communication to a specific client unless that client already issued a connection to the server.
  That means that in order to achieve a prestigious online full duplex communication with all your clients - all your clients must maintain an open port to the server.
- Having a dual client and server per PC in order to achieve an online full duplex is a step forward as it will solve the issue of keeping a port open per client however it has downsides in terms of security as it means that the specific PC is open to receive multiple connection requests. Another issue can occur with deadly reentrancies if you not careful. So, basically you will be saving 'ports' in exchange for architecture
  maintainability and fitness to your solution.

So if you are targeting a deployment of around 200-300 PC's your architecture will hold but if you are targeting a larger deployment of thousands of PC's - it will not hold.

Comment: it is about 300 pc's in an intranet environment. hence i take it you agree with our architecture?

Comment: yes, for 300 pc's in an intranet environment it will hold ok.

Comment: what would you suggest for a system that needed to be scaled upto say 5000 pc's?

Comment: I would suggest a tcp/ip server which make use of IOCP (Input Output Completion Ports) with an application level protocol. 
Not http request-response, meaning not a WCF based server.